# Why can't UIDocumentPickerViewController choose PDFs?

Tags: ios

I am using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in Import mode and it shows PDFs on iCloud and Dropbox. However they are all greyed out and I cannot select them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you specifying the right document types? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/1618678-init

Answer (score 11):

**First**

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

now you're eable to access new values such as

`String(kUTTypePDF)`

**Finally**, in your Document View Controller

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
```

enjoy

Comment: There is no need to create a new string, you can just cast it

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide the types of documents that the user is allowed to select.

```
let docTypes = [
        "com.adobe.pdf"
    ]

let docViewCtlr = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: docTypes, in: .import)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
@IBAction func PdfBtn(_ sender: Any) {

     let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: 
          ["public.composite-content"], in: .import)

     importMenu.delegate = self
     present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 14 or later, use [`init(forOpeningContentTypes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3566732-init)

```swift
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

let pickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [
     UTType.pdf
])
pickerViewController.delegate = self
present(pickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```